# Identifying 'upstream' merge commits, not from within a fork

Tags: git, github

I am trying to identify pull request merge commits in the git history.

We can normally use something like:

```
git log --merges |grep 'Merge pull request'`
```

However, I am part of a distributed project with several repository forks, and have found that pull request merge commits that were part of the fork's development stream are polluting this output.  This is even observed in Github's UI.

Example:

```
18b389... Merge pull request #2222 from Fork/master  <-- Fork/master to Upstream/master for feature X -  Want.
ea3e5b... Merge pull request #12 from Fork/feature-x  <-- Fork/feature-x to Fork/master - Dont want.
```

I would like to isolate only merge commits between forks and upstream, not between branches of forks or forks-of-a-fork.  Is this possible?

My actual goal is to be able to identify all pull request merge commit SHAs between a range of commits, but these errant commits pollute the results with references to unrelated PRs - there is no distinction between fork and upstream in the commit message.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are really trying to do, but a "fork" is really just another clone of a repository. If you have a merge in your repository, you either made the merge yourself, or you got it from someone else (who may have [gotten it from somenoe else yet again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jKiunSRzAI)), but as far as Git is concerned, that doesn't matter. The *origin* of a commit is not traceable, in general; all you can tell is "yes I have it" or "no I don't".

Comment: Yes, that is in fact what I would like to do.  Our project has development done in the fork, and code review/final integration testing/releases managed in pull requests to the upstream/parent. I'd like to be able to run some analysis on only the merge commits resulting from these upstream pulls, but it looks like git cli is not going to be the tool for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do 100 % reliably. But here are some ways to get get close:

- can you `grep` on some other part of the commit message?
- can you browse the list of pull requests on the GitHub page of Upstream?
- Try to add the `--first-parent` switch to your call to `git log`. This might not give you all relevant pull requests, but it should not give you any of the ones you don't want.

`--first-parent` tells `git log` to only follow the first parent of a merge commit, as opposed to following all parents. The branch being merged into is always the first parent, so it's an effective way to see just the history that happened directly on the branch you are looking at.

Sadly, there is one thing that can mess up the first-parent history, namely the merge that happens when someone pulls. If Person A is working directly on the master, and something else is pushed to the server in the meantime, a merge will happen (unless configured otherwise) when A pulls. And in this case, A's local commits will be the first parent, and whatever was pushed in the meantime will be the second parent, which means it will not show up under `git log --first-parent`.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using Github's API to get the actual merge shas, and then verified that all were present in `git log`.  Thanks for the help.